# Installing Python on Linux Mint

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint

I have been trying to install python3.3.0 on Linux Mint. After reading the README file, I ran the following commands:

```
 ./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

I ran the `make test` command, but it  gave skipped a few tests sayig that it could not find the required modules and gave the following errors:

```
     FAIL: test_urlwithfrag (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Python-3.3.0/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 165, in test_urlwithfrag
    "http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#glossary")
AssertionError: 'http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html' != 'http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#glossary'
- http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html
?                        --
+ http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#glossary
?  

                               +++++++++

Ran 15 tests in 58.905s

FAILED (failures=1, skipped=1)
test test_urllib2net failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Please tell me what I need to do to get python working on my system

Answer (score 2):

What are you planning on using Python for? (Reply as a comment)

It is a very bad idea to install a newer version of Python on your system itself, as it could break a lot of functionality of the OS (as the OS is built using a specific version of Python).

I recommend you consider using a tool like:

https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew (deprecated but still works)

OR

https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv (alternative recommended)

These tools will act like a kind of sandbox and make installing different versions possible without breaking the functionality of the OS.

Comment: "It is a very bad idea to install a newer version of Python on your system itself, as it could break a lot of functionality of the OS" - that's only true if you plan to replace the default python version with it. In a sane OS, there's no problem with installing multiple python versions side by side; I've got 2.6, 2.7 and 3.3 installed on my xubuntu system without breaking anything.

Comment: Good point. You can install multiple versions side by side, but that is more complex then the sandbox method (which I found much easier to install and use). I don't get the thumbs down for my answer either, but its cool.

Answer (score 1):

That bug is reported [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue16969).

I had the same error and python3 works fine, however, before you install please install the following dependencies. It will save you many hours of pain that I had to go through trying to get tkinter to work (note that several of the following don't exist, but just go through the motions as I forget which ones aren't relevent anymore):

- sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
- sudo apt-get install build-essential
- sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev
- sudo apt-get install libreadline5-dev
- sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
- sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev
- sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
- sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
- sudo apt-get install tk-dev
- sudo apt-get install python-support

You will still get the same error about test_urllib2net but it isn't anything that will halt you in the future (at least I don't think so based on the bug report listed above).

Comment: This is quite a while ago, but it fixed my trouble today. Thank you!